# Why is general relativity in (2+1) dimensions different from cylindrical systems in (3+1) dimensional GR?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, potential, spacetime-dimensions, cosmic-string

The gravitational potential $\Phi$ of an infinite rod in newtonian gravity is $\Phi \sim \ln(r)$. This is the same as the gravitational potential of a point charge in two-dimensional Newtonian gravity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_potential). They are the same, because both systems exhibit cylindrical symmetry and Gauss Law yields a logarithmic potential in this case.

In general relativity the solution for a static cylindrical spacetime is the Levi-Civita spacetime, which in the Newtonian limit will also give a potential $\Phi \sim \ln(r)$ (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06561).

But what I can't understand is that in (2+1) dimensional general relativity it is said the spacetime is flat outside of a mass point, so in the Newtonian limit $\Phi \sim 0$. This is claimed despite authors stating that a point particle in general relativity in (2+1) dimensions is equivalent to a (infinite) string in (3+1) dimensions.

> "We discussed the global properties of the (locally flat) geometries generated by moving point particles in 2+1 dimensions, or equivalently by parallel moving cosmic strings in 3+1 dimensions." ([Deser, Jackiw, t'Hooft (1992)](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/73388/))

> "There is also a close relation to cosmic strings in four dimensions since the space-time of an infinite straight string is effectively three-dimensional."  ([Deser, Jackiw (1988)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-118/issue-3/Classical-and-quantum-scattering-on-a-cone/cmp/1104162096.full))

So why is there a difference between Newtonian Potential derived from Levi-Civita spacetime and the Newtonian potential derived from a (2+1) dimensional general relativity? Is general relativity in (2+1) dimensions not simply a cross section through a cylindrical symmetric spacetime in (3+1) dimensions? What is it then?

Comment: About the last question: think about weyl curvature, which carries gravitational degrees of freedom vanishes identically in (2+1) dim, but is non-zero in (3+1) dim spacetimes. The curvatures appearing in EFE are the intrinsic curvatures of space time. If you take cross-section , then you will also have to take into account the extrinsic curvatures, depending on how you define the cross section.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question! Let us consider [vacuum solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity)) to the [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) with zero cosmological constant $\Lambda=0$:

1. The static axisymmetric/cylindrical spacetimes in 3+1D are classified by Levi-Civita solutions [1,2]. They represent a (possibly thick$^1$) [cosmic string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) of total zero angular momentum $J=0$. There are effectively 2 parameters:

   - $\sigma$, which has an interpretation of an energy-density per length of the string.
   - A [deficit angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect).

   If there is no deficit angle, then the well-known Newtonian limit (with an attractive Newtonian $ln$ potential) exists and corresponds to the limit $\sigma\to 0^+$.
2. The static spherical symmetric spacetimes in 2+1D. The corresponding [Schwarzschild-like](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585604/2451)$^2$ solution is locally on [Minkowski-form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209012/2451)$^3$, and it has only 1 topological parameter: A deficit angle, which grows with the mass of the point source.

In both cases, if there is a deficit angle, it extends all the way to $r=\infty$, i.e. there is no asymptotic region $r=\infty$ unaffected by the string/point source, and hence there is no Newtonian limit.

Perhaps surprisingly, in 2+1D the Newtonian $ln$ potential has no analog in [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200020/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. M.F.A. da Silva, L. Herrera, F.M. Paiva, & N.O. Santos, *The Levi-Civita spacetime,* [arXiv:gr-qc/9607058](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9607058)
   .
2. K. Bronnikov, N.O. Santos, & Anzhong Wang, *Cylindrical Systems in General Relativity,* [arXiv:1901.06561](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06561)
   .

--

$^1$ Angular motion of the thick cosmic string is not completely prohibited, which leads to 1 extra parameter, that saves the $\ln$ potential. This is the main answer to OP's title question.

$^2$ Not a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole)!

$^3$ This is related to the fact that GR in 2+1D is a topological field theory (TFT).