# How to find the deficit angle of the BTZ black hole?

Tags: black-holes, topology

I've read the the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/680025/why-is-general-relativity-in-21-dimensions-different-from-cylindrical-systems/680333#680333) where it is claimed that the BTZ black hole has a deficit angle. How can we see that in the BTZ case and in general?

Comment: The linked answer makes no such claims. BTZ black hole is asymptotically AdS, deficit angle does not makes sense for it.

Comment: @A.V.S. While I agree that the linked answer does not mention BTZ black holes (let alone whether they have a deficit angle), the singularity in a BTZ black hole is a conical singularity, and one can ascribe a deficit angle to it.

Comment: @mmeent: The [BHTZ paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9302012) explicitly states that their “singularity” at “$r = 0$ is not a conical singularity”  (outside of unphysical case of negative mass, which is not a black hole).

Comment: @A.V.S. That is because $r=0$ is not a singularity at all. The BTZ spacetime can be continued to negative $r$ (where it has a true conical singularity).

Comment: @mmeent negative $r$ is the region of CTCs (which is why the authors excise it and call $r=0$ singularity of causal structure) Do you mean then “conical” in the Lorentzian sense (as opposed to 2D Riemmanian)?

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes, in the Lorentzian sense (or I guess in this case in the locally AdS sense.)

Comment: @mmeent But how are you defining the *deficit angle* on a Lorentzian cone?